# how to make changes to a variable that have been done in a function affect the variable globally python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, cryptography

I'm making a python program that uses tkinter and cryptography modules that encrypts and decrypts text with an interface. My problem is with my class that i use an instance of in the main program. The problem is that the changes done to a global variable not affecting the variable outside of its scope. I know it's bad practice, but i cannot think of a way to do this without doing that, because i need to do the encrypting in the function and do need to have a separate function for decrypting the message. I basically have two buttons that call on these functions. If you can think of another way i would be very thankful. Also the error is "NameError: name 'token' is not defined"

```
import tkinter
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

global token

class Cryptography:

    def encrypt(self, string):
        byteString = str.encode(string)
        token = f.encrypt(byteString)
        w.insert(tkinter.INSERT, token.decode() + "\n")
        w.pack()

    def decrypt(self):
        try:
            decrypted = f.decrypt(token)
        except NameError:
            w.insert(tkinter.INSERT, "you didn't yet encrypt anything\n")
            w.pack()
        decrypted = f.decrypt(token)
        dsAsString = decrypted.decode("utf-8")
        w.insert(tkinter.INSERT, dsAsString + "\n")
```

Comment: you define `global` in the wrong place. Defining global in the global namespace does nothing. You need to define global in the function/method directly. That said you should not be using global with a class. Instead move `token` into the class and and use it as a class attribute instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare your variable using `self` so that you can directly access it in other methods of your class since both `encrypt` and `decrypt` are the methods belonging to the same class.

```
class Cryptography:

    def encrypt(self, string):
        byteString = str.encode(string)
        self.token = f.encrypt(byteString) # <--- self type here
        w.insert(tkinter.INSERT, token.decode() + "\n")
        w.pack()

    def decrypt(self):
        try:
            decrypted = f.decrypt(self.token) # <--- self.token here
        except NameError:
            w.insert(tkinter.INSERT, "you didn't yet encrypt anything\n")
            w.pack()
        decrypted = f.decrypt(self.token) # <---- self.token used here
        dsAsString = decrypted.decode("utf-8")
        w.insert(tkinter.INSERT, dsAsString + "\n")
```

Alternatively, the `global` declaration should be done in the `decrypt` function

```
def decrypt(self):
        global token
        try:
            decrypted = f.decrypt(token)
        except NameError:
            w.insert(tkinter.INSERT, "you didn't yet encrypt anything\n")
            w.pack()
        decrypted = f.decrypt(token)
        dsAsString = decrypted.decode("utf-8")
        w.insert(tkinter.INSERT, dsAsString + "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

you define global in the wrong place. Defining global in the global namespace does nothing. You need to define global in the function/method directly. That said you should not be using global with a class. Instead move token into the class and and use it as a class attribute instead.

```
import tkinter
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet


class Cryptography:
    def __init__(self):
        self.token = ''

    def encrypt(self, string):
        byteString = str.encode(string)
        self.token = f.encrypt(byteString)
        w.insert(tkinter.INSERT, self.token.decode() + "\n")
        w.pack()

    def decrypt(self):
        try:
            decrypted = f.decrypt(self.token)
        except NameError:
            w.insert(tkinter.INSERT, "you didn't yet encrypt anything\n")
            w.pack()
        decrypted = f.decrypt(self.token)
        dsAsString = decrypted.decode("utf-8")
        w.insert(tkinter.INSERT, dsAsString + "\n")
```

Comment: Wouldn't it work with using self.token directly in the `encrypt` without initializing it in  `__init__`?

Comment: @Bazingaa probably. I am just use to writing class's this way as I often build tkinter GUI.

Comment: @Bazingaa as long as you use `self.` to define it as a class attribute it should be fine to leave it in the methods and not use `__init__` in this case. Unless you try to run decrypt without running encrypt first.

Comment: Yes, that's what I remember. So both our answers should work.

Comment: @Bazingaa both should work. I just like to avoid `global` whenever possible.

Comment: My answer doesn't use `global` as well. I gave two answers. One of them with global, one without global